# How to properly set values to same type of composition members

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

Say I have a class called Person, who owns three kinds of pets:

```
class Person
{
public:
    accept(Pet a);
private:
    Dog d;  // is a Pet
    Cat c;  // is a Pet
    Fish f; // is a Pet
}

Person::accept(Pet a)
{
    // if pet is Dog, then
    d = a;
    // if pet is Cat, then
    c = a;
    // if pet is Fish, then
    f = a;
};
```

I guess `typeid` can be used here. However, it still looks weird to me.

Is there some kind of polymorphism, virtual function or some OOP pattern that can be applied?

-- EDIT --

Sorry for the bad example here. Let me try another one:

```
// Usually a context contains three different resources:
class Context
{
public:
    setResource(Resource *r);
private:
    Buffer *b_;    // is a Resource
    Kernel *k_;    // is a Resource
    Sampler *s_;   // is a Resource
};
Context::setResource(Resource *r) { // same logic as Person::accept() above }
Context::handlingBuffer() { if (b_) b_->init(); ... }
Context::run() { 
    if (b_ && k_) { 
        k_.setBuffer(b_); 
        k_.run(); 
    }
}
...
```

In this case, looks like adding a `Resource *r_[3]` in `Context` will make things more complicated.

So, is it possible to pass a pointer of base class of Resource to `setResource()`, and it can automatically decide which resource to set?

Comment: If Dog, Cat, and Fish are *derivations* of Pet, you have more problems than you may first think.

Comment: Polymorphism is more about different behaviour of objects that are used in the same manner (by using type they're derived from), for example: `Person::feed(Pet* p){ p->makeSound(); }` which would result into some specific behaviour of the pet based on its type... `typeid` is typical [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) which is quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @molbdnilo, I found a simpler way to achieve my goal:

```
class Resource
{
public:
    virtual void AddToContext(Context* c) = 0;
};

class Buffer : public Resource
{
public:
    void AddToContext(Context* c) { c->SetResource(this); }
};

// Likewise for Kernel and Sampler

class Context
{
public:
    void SetResource(Resource *r) { r->AddToContext(this); }
    void SetResource(Buffer *b) { b_ = b; }
    void SetResource(Kernel *k) { k_ = k; }
    void SetResource(Sampler *s) { s_ = s; }
    ...
private:
    Buffer *b_;
    Kernel *k_;
    Sampler *s_;
};
```

It is not quite like Visitor pattern at this point, but it is relatively concise and works great.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are holding `Pets` by value, you can forget polymorphism and just overload the `accept` member function:

```
class Person
{
public:
    accept(const Dog& a)  { d_ = a; }
    accept(const Cat& a)  { c_ = a; }
    accept(const Fish& a) { f_ = a; }
private:
    Dog d_;  // is a Pet
    Cat c_;  // is a Pet
    Fish f_; // is a Pet
};
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if holding `Pets` by pointer? - updated my question.

Comment: @Deqing if you really want to use runtime polymorphism, then you should hold (smart) pointers to the base type, `Pet`, and not to the derived types. Then the caller can just pass pointers to `Pet`, but pointing to a contrete type. The details depend on the ownership policy (i.e. who is responsible for deleting the objects pointed at, the caller, the `Person` class, nobody?).

Comment: I got your point. However, in my real case looks like it is hard to apply. Had updated my question, any ideas?

Comment: @Deqing You could check whether you can `dynamic_cast` to each derived type. If `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(Base*)` succeeds, then assign to the variable of `Derived*`. This is ugly though. I suggest a re-design.

Answer (score 1):

A common method to letting code depend on the runtime type is *double dispatch*, a.k.a. the Visitor pattern:

```
class ResourceContext
{
public:
    virtual void setResource(Buffer* r) = 0;
    virtual void setResource(Kernel* r) = 0;
    virtual void setResource(Sampler* r) = 0;
};

class Resource
{
public:
    virtual void AddToContext(ResourceContext* cxt) = 0;

    [... rest of Resource ...]
};

class Buffer : public Resource
{
public:
     void AddToContext(ResourceContext* cxt) { cxt->SetResource(this); }
};

// Likewise for Kernel and Sampler.

class Context : public ResourceContext
{
public:
    void setResource(Resource* r) { r->AddToContext(this); }
    void setResource(Buffer *r)  { b_ = r; }
    void setResource(Kernel *r)  { k_ = r; }
    void setResource(Sampler *r) { s_ = r; }
private:
    Buffer *b_;    // is a Resource
    Kernel *k_;    // is a Resource
    Sampler *s_;   // is a Resource
};
```

Comment: Yes.. the Visitor pattern. When I came across this situation, I feel some pattern should be able to apply here, but just can't remember. Thanks! Though it really increases code complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example code, I agree with juanchopanza. However, if you want to keep the structure of your `class Person` with pointers, you could use `dynamic_cast<>`, e.g.

```
struct Pet { /* ... */ };
struct Dog : public Pet { /* ... */ };
struct Cat : public Pet { /* ... */ };
struct Fish : public Pet { /* ... */ };
struct Spider : public Pet { /* ... */ };

class Person {
  Dog*dog;
  Cat*cat;
  Fish*fish;
  Spider*yuck;

  template<typename PetType>
  static bool accept_pet(Pet*pet, PetType*&my_pet)
  {
    PetType*p = dynamic_cast<PetType*>(pet);
    if(p) {
      my_pet = p;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
public:
  Person()
  : dog(0), cat(0), fish(0), yuck(0) {}
  void accept(Pet*pet)
  {
    if(accept_pet(pet,dog)) return;
    if(accept_pet(pet,cat)) return;
    if(accept_pet(pet,fish)) return;
    if(accept_pet(pet,yuck)) return;
    throw unknown_pet();
  }
};
```

I should add, that `dynamic_cast<>` should be avoided if it can. Often (but not always) a design that makes a `dynamic_cast<>` necessary can be improved to avoid that. This also applies here, when simply overloading the `accept()` (as in juanchopanza's answer) is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For me the approach itself looks wrong. As @LihO said in his comment, polymorphism helps to treat different type objects in the same manner. So from polymorphism point of view, your design should look as:

```
// Usually a context contains three different resources:
class Context
{
public:
    setResource(Resource *r);
private:
    std::vector<Resource*> resources_;
};
```

The rest should be resolved by virtual functions of `Resource` class.

Using `dynamic_cast` often means your design is not perfect.